# Transferring variable without global; Issues with Return

Tags: python-2.7, variables, global-variables, return-value

Working on a piece of code; The only way I can get it to work at the moment is by using global variables. I'd like to do it by using return, but when I do so it gives me the whole jumble of the function when I call the variable using "n = genTable()" for example.

```
def genTable():
    global n
    n = Min #n starts as min
    print ("%-6s %-6s %-6s %s" %("n", "Seq", "Bin", "Perf")) #Header
    print "--------------------------------" #Header
    while n <= Max:
        Seq = seqCalc() #Calls calculation for sequential
        Bin = binCalc() #Calls calculation for binary
        if n > 0:
            Perf = round(Seq / Bin) #Calculate Performance
        else:
            Perf = 0
        print ("%-6s %-6s %-6s %s" %(n, Seq, int(Bin), int(Perf))) #Prints results
        n = n + Int

def seqCalc():
    Seq = n / 2 #Sequential Calculation
    return Seq
```

I have omitted other variables from other functions; Just concerned with n right now. (Ignore Bin)

Is there a way to call return without getting the whole mess of the function repeated by "seqCalc"?

Comment: You need the value of `n` within `seqCalc` so you should pass `n` as an argument to `seqCalc`. I.e., `def seqCalc(n):...` then call it like `Seq = seqCalc(n)`. Are you following some tutorial?

Comment: Just coding for a project. Not following any tutorials, just like to comment so I know what does what. 

The taking an argument in the function seems to have worked! I appreciate it!